# Вызвать удаленный метод С++ из Java

Tags: rpc, rmi, java, c++

Здравствуйте,
Меня интересуют механизмы, которые могли бы вызывать удаленные методы С++ из Java кода.
Если бы весь код был на Java - использовал бы RMI.
Читал что-то о Corba, но везде пишут, что проект мертв.
Может SOAP?

Comment: в Хорстмане 2 том стр. 916 *вызов функции на языке С из Java*. Ничего про это сказать толком не могу(слабо знаком и ни разу не пользовался), может чем то эта информация пригодится.

Comment: спасибо, как раз там прочитал про RMI. На счет Corba у него было написано "RMI заполонила и вытеснила Corba, поетому корбьа рассмотрена не будет". Оттуда же читал про JNA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать мостик [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), то есть вокруг удаленного метода С++ сооружаем Java класс с JNI мостиком к сишным функциям, далее уже между Java-Java организуем RMI

Comment: как вариант - да. Но не сложновато ли? Наверняка же кто-то уже встречался с такими проблемами. Механизм, который я видел, был написан на двух сокетах(один на яве, второй на си) со своей серилизацией, по которым бегали данные в собственном протоколе. Именно поетому и интересно, существуют ли готовые решения

Comment: Ну раз так то ничего кроме CORBA в голову не приходит. Посмотри в сторону пакета 'org.omg' входящему в состав JDK - это имплементация CORBA для JVM

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернативу `JNI` и `SOAP'у` могу предложить вам использовать [**Google Protobuf**](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) и обмениваться сообщениями при работе с сервисом.

Answer (score 2):

Тогда можно упомянуть и [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), как альтернативу `protobuf`-у